# Perché si usa l'apostrofo per indicare alcuni casi di troncamento ma non tutti?

Tags: orthography

"Errori" di ortografia frequenti nei bambini a scuola, e negli adulti che studiano l'italiano come lingua straniera, sono nell'uso dell'apostrofo.

Quali sono le motivazioni storiche per cui:

- il troncamento generalmente non lascia alcun segno diacritico (es: u**n** altro)
- il troncamento lascia un apostrofo in alcune parole (es.: **po'**, **mo'**)
- parole che hanno perso la sillaba finale *ab antiquo* (non so se si possa definire troncamento) hanno un accento e non un apostrofo (*civitatem* > città).

Domanda bonus ma attinente: c'è una sostanziale differenza tra l'"elisione" di una > un' e il "troncamento" di uno > un, oppure il segno diacritico è puramente per marcare la differenza di genere?

Comment: In attesa che qualcuno possa scrivere una risposta: sì, c'è una differenza sostanziale e si vede nel fatto che le forme tronche hanno, per così dire, un'esistenza autonoma. Si dice “un uomo” ma anche “un cane”, mentre “un'” dipende strettamente dalla presenza di una vocale: “un'ape” ma “una tigre”. È lo stesso discorso del perché “qual è” si scrive senza apostrofo: “qual” è una parola (tronca) che si può usare anche di per sé (“per la qual cosa”, “qual buon vento ti porta” etc.).

Comment: Invece “piede” diventa “piè”. Non cercherei motivazioni profonde: po‘ mo‘ ca‘ si scrivono così perché di sì. Gli imperativi da’ di‘ fa’ sta’ va’ hanno una storia diversa. Storicamente, l'accento su parole come “città” era un apostrofo che poi ha cambiato posto.

Answer (score 2):

Non chiamerei l’apostrofo un segno diacritico, ma non è molto importante.

Nell’ortografia italiana, così com’è oggi, ci sono alcune particolarità:

- l’accento grafico obbligatorio sulle parole ossitone;
- apostrofo per l’elisione;
- nessun segno per il troncamento, con qualche eccezione.

Le eccezioni sul troncamento sono le note parole

> po’ mo’ ca’ fra’

(il Treccani però dice che *fra’* e *frà* sono meno comuni di *fra*), gli imperativi

> da’ di’ fa’ sta’ va’

(che hanno un’origine propria e indicano forme dell’imperativo sviluppatesi a fianco di *dai dici fai stai vai*) e altri che vogliono l’accento come *piè*.

Di fatto, l’accento sulle parole ossitone era un apostrofo che indicava la caduta della sillaba finale e poi si trasferì sulla vocale. La distinzione fra accento acuto e grave è recente.

A parte questi casi, il troncamento non si segnala. Come distinguere? La regola pratica è vedere se la parola “mozzata” ha “vita propria”:

> un albero, un disegno
> nessun impegno, nessun gioco
> qual è, qual buon vento

(Fra parentesi: l'italiano ha *due* articoli indeterminativi, cioè *uno* e *una*, solo che il primo ubbidisce alle regole fonetiche che impongono certi troncamenti.)

Se la parola “mozzata” può essere adoperata davanti a consonante, nessun segno. Al contrario

> un’ora, una vignetta

L’articolo *una* non può essere “mozzato” davanti a consonante, quindi vuole l’apostrofo.

Si può restare incerti se si debba [scrivere *pover’uomo* o *pover uomo*](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/P/pover-uomo.shtml), visto che *pover tapin* è negli immortali versi di “Ho visto un re”, ma direi che certi troncamenti usati in poesia non fanno regola.

Non credo che la domanda sul perché certi troncamenti si segnino con l’apostrofo abbia risposta: qual è la differenza fra *po’* e *piè*? Non ne vedo. L’unica spiegazione è che la tradizione ortografica ormai è questa.